# Unity ARCore simple object movement across network

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, cloud

I'm currently developing an android application using Google's ARCore and cloud anchors and I am having a problem with getting objects to change location across the network on button click. The problem has to be somewhere surrounding the actual button because I know that the button runs the function but it doesn't do what I want it to do, if I call the function from player script it works fine (but I need this to work on button click!) and I've been stuck with it for days now. Some enlightenment here would be very appreciated. If anyone's wondering, I'm simply trying to edit (as I'm learning) the example code of cloud anchors therefore the source code belongs to Google. 
[Code I'm stuck with][1]

What I'm trying to achieve is a simple transform.Translate on an object and make this move visible to clients.

Things to note:
Button has network identity
Different functions to make any kind of movement/rotation
Player prefab has network identity
object prefabs in question have network transform component

My code are presented below:

```
    [Command]
    public void CmdSpawnStar(Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation)
    {
        //if conditional that stops further object placement until touchCounter is reset to a 0
        if (touchCounter == 0)
        {


            // the object at hit pose
            PlaceableModel = Instantiate(StarPrefab, position, rotation);
            PlaceableModel.transform.Rotate(0, k_ModelRotation, 0, Space.Self);// Compensate for the hitPose rotation facing away from the raycast (i.e. camera).


            NetworkServer.Spawn(PlaceableModel);

            touchCounter++;

        } 

    }

    [Command]
    public void CmdFlyUp()
    {
        _ShowAndroidToastMessage("UP button is pressed");
        PlaceableModel.transform.Translate(0, 0.1f, 0);

    }
```

Comment: Add your code in text, not as an image.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, I have just added